# SSRS Report Builder to show variables without assigned systems

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Okay, I am going to try and explain this in a way that will make sense in the question that I am needing help with. Let's say that I have over 100 locations that I am pulling data from in a report that I have built already.

The following columns have the correct data coming through for each location:

User | Active | Admin | Organization | Department

---

**User Column**: This is where the name of the user is display

**Active**: This is if that user has an active account on that location

**Admin**: This is if that user has an admin account at the location

**Organization**: This is to display the organization for that particular location provides

**Department**: This is to display in what department of where the user works

---

Before I get into the question, I have a parameter set up to where the person receiving the report will have to choose the location that they are wanting to see before the report is shown. Another way to state that is to say the parameter is set to show only those users in that location once a locations is selected.

The question I have for a client is that some users are admins and those admins have access over 2 organizations. But some new users are not attached to an organization just yet. Is there a way for me to format a column/subreport to show those individuals that are not attached to an organization? I would be eternally grateful for someone to walk through the logic with me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why can't the organization field just be blank? It would help if you could show a sample of how you expect the results to look.

Comment: How would I be able to show it blank if the individual is not attached to anything yet. And my client would like for that to show up in that format as well